# Twitter API using ASp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter

I know how to register an APP for Twitter so I can get Authorization and client ID, Client Secret etc.

However I am curious how do I call the API to get information from twitter.
For example I want to get certain tweets from certain people on Twitter. For example bill gates. I want Bill gates, Steve woz and Mark Cubans latest tweets.
How would I got about forming these API calls.

Also would it be good to use the WEB API or use Rest calls?

Also PS I am a lost noob right now.

Comment: You can find all endpoints in the twitter api documentation. https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api

Answer (score 1):

Import linq2twitter library: `using LinqToTwitter;`

Generate the authentication prerequisites first:

```
            var auth = new SingleUserAuthorizer
            {
                CredentialStore = new InMemoryCredentialStore
                {
                    ConsumerKey = "consumerKey",
                    ConsumerSecret = "consumerSecret",
                    OAuthToken = "oAuthToken",
                    OAuthTokenSecret = "oAuthSecret"
                }
            };
            var context = new TwitterContext(auth);
            var container = await DoPagedSearchAsync(context, this);
```

The following function returns Tweets in the form of a list class -> Statuses.

```
        static async Task<List<Tweet>> DoPagedSearchAsync(TwitterContext twitterCtx, Acquirer formx)
        {
        formx.Enabled = false;
        int MaxSearchEntriesToReturn = 50; //number of results per loop (int)
        int MaxTotalResults = 250; //total number of results (int)
        formx.progressBar1.Maximum = MaxTotalResults;
        string searchTerm = "String to search";
        ulong sinceID = 1;
        ulong maxID;
        List<Status> combinedSearchResults = new List<Status>();
        List<Status> searchResponse =
            await
            (from search in twitterCtx.Search
             where search.Type == SearchType.Search &&
                   search.Query == searchTerm &&
                   search.Count == MaxSearchEntriesToReturn &&
                   search.SinceID == sinceID
             select search.Statuses)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

        if (searchResponse != null)
        {
            combinedSearchResults.AddRange(searchResponse);
            ulong previousMaxID = ulong.MaxValue;
            do
            {
                maxID = searchResponse.Min(status => status.StatusID) - 1;

                Debug.Assert(maxID < previousMaxID);
                previousMaxID = maxID;

                searchResponse =
                    await
                    (from search in twitterCtx.Search
                     where search.Type == SearchType.Search &&
                           search.Query == searchTerm &&
                           search.Count == MaxSearchEntriesToReturn &&
                           search.MaxID == maxID &&
                           search.SinceID == sinceID
                     select search.Statuses)
                    .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

                combinedSearchResults.AddRange(searchResponse);
                try
                {
                    formx.progressBar1.Value = combinedSearchResults.Count;
                }
                catch
                { }
            } while (searchResponse.Any() && combinedSearchResults.Count <= (MaxTotalResults - MaxSearchEntriesToReturn));
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No results obtained");
            formx.progressBar1.Value = 0;
            formx.Enabled = true;
            return null;
        }
        var package = parser(combinedSearchResults, formx);
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            return package;
        });
    }
```

Comment: With your code you posted do I need to install a library using nuget? I have seen libraries like Tweet sharp ,but I am unsure.

Comment: you need to install Linq2Twitter from Nuget

Comment: So I need to instal linq2twitter for the above posted code to work?

Comment: Absolutely. It will make everything really easy, simple and convenient.

Comment: What using's do I need for the code segments.

Comment: I get an error about the task and Debug.Assert part

Comment: Also I am getting an error for the "var auth = new SingleUserAuthorizer" section. Var is that a data type for .NET ???? O.o

Comment: @ComSciDevGuy  var means dynamic, you can use the data type it is being initialized to instead if you have an issue with var

Comment: @ComSciDevGuy you don't have to use `Async` / `Await` if they throw exceptions. It ain't necassary